# Application window has become incredibly wide, almost unusable

Tags: window-manager, window

Today my Soulseek client window has become so wide that it's almost unusable. I can see the border resize icon, but can only resize it for wider, as if a "minimal width" setting is in place. The height has no restraints. The window context menu has the Minimize option available, the Maximize is disabled. Selecting "Resize" from this menu is the same as with the mouse. When I double-click the title bar (which usually maximizes the window), nothing happens. I tried the "Reset Window and Column Size Settings" button in Options|UI, and even after restart the program and the computer, nothing happens. I found [this similar issue](http://www.soulseekqt.net/news/node/3398), but no solution yet.

I'm using SoulseekQt build 2016.1.17 on Debian Jessie 64-bit, GNOME Version 3.14.1.

As suggested in the comments, here is the relevant part of `xprop` output (specially **program specified minimum size: 4885 by 630**):

```
_NET_WM_USER_TIME_WINDOW(WINDOW): window id # 0x200000c
_NET_WM_STATE(ATOM) = 
WM_STATE(WM_STATE):
        window state: Normal
        icon window: 0x0
_NET_WM_DESKTOP(CARDINAL) = 0
_NET_FRAME_EXTENTS(CARDINAL) = 1, 1, 39, 1
_NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS(ATOM) = _NET_WM_ACTION_MOVE, _NET_WM_ACTION_RESIZE, _NET_WM_ACTION_FULLSCREEN, _NET_WM_ACTION_MINIMIZE, _NET_WM_ACTION_SHADE, _NET_WM_ACTION_MAXIMIZE_HORZ, _NET_WM_ACTION_MAXIMIZE_VERT, _NET_WM_ACTION_CHANGE_DESKTOP, _NET_WM_ACTION_CLOSE, _NET_WM_ACTION_ABOVE, _NET_WM_ACTION_BELOW
XdndAware(ATOM) = BITMAP
_NET_WM_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "SoulseekQt build 2016.1.17 [...]"
_MOTIF_WM_HINTS(_MOTIF_WM_HINTS) = 0x3, 0x3e, 0x7e, 0x0, 0x0
_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL
_XEMBED_INFO(_XEMBED_INFO) = 0x0, 0x1
WM_CLIENT_LEADER(WINDOW): window id # 0x2000002
WM_HINTS(WM_HINTS):
        Client accepts input or input focus: True
        Initial state is Normal State.
_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 1885
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "SoulseekQt-2016-1-17-64bit", "SoulseekQt-2016-1-17-64bit"
WM_PROTOCOLS(ATOM): protocols  WM_DELETE_WINDOW, WM_TAKE_FOCUS, _NET_WM_PING
WM_NORMAL_HINTS(WM_SIZE_HINTS):
        user specified location: 1, 314
        user specified size: 4885 by 691
        program specified minimum size: 4885 by 630
        window gravity: Static
```

Comment: So Soulseek requests an extremely wide minimum window size, and the window manager honors that. Find out why the program does it (inspect config files, etc., and modify as appropriate).

Comment: @dirkt I'll look for it. The question is: why it did this s*** all of a sudden?

Comment: I don't know the application. Something in how you used the application must have caused a configuration change, leading to this wide window.

Comment: @dirkt Looks like the config file is soulseek-client.dat.1488890831520, located in ~/.SoulseekQt/1. But it has more than 6 MB, and it's not a plain text file. Maybe if I delete them (there are 3 copies), but then I'll lose the remaining of the configuration (such as users list). What I'd really like to understand is how such a crazy configuration appeared in first place.

Comment: @dirkt Right, I needed to delete all 3 config files. Thus I lost my username, needed to re-share my shared folders, and also lost users from the user list and downloads in the queue. Now I remember, I sent my username for a friend via WhatsApp the day before this strange behavior, could it have anything to do with it?

Comment: No need to *delete* the files. And before doing something like this, just make a copy, so you can fill in the information again (with a text editor, if necessary). As I said, I've no idea what could have caused it. Possibly a bug in the Soulseek client, possibly just an unintended sideeffect of something you did.

Answer (score 0):

At: https://groups.google.com/g/soulseek-discussion/c/j2aTmofseqk

User hitmei...@gmail.com

Wrote:

> Options > General > Clear Search History.... then adjust it... close and open it. Problem solved.